# Android Studio: Calling activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I used the below code to call an activity from another one

```
Intent launch = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class); 
startActivity(launch);
```

I use a button to call the activity2 in activity1, whenever I click the button I only get my activity1 with a white colour shade below it.

Comment: Show your AndroidManifest.xml file, your layout file and your activity1 class. It's difficult otherwise to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
 <activity
            android:name="Activity1"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:label="@string/app_alias" >

        </activity>
 <activity
            android:name="Activity2"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:label="@string/app_alias" >

        </activity>
```

Comment: What do I have to do with the AndriodManifest file ?

Comment: add activty tag if you did not it before, @DineshAdhithya